# Diff several files, true if all not equal

Tags: bash, diff

I have a number of files, I want to check that all those files have the same content.

What command line could I use to check that?

Usage could be something like:

```
$ diffseveral file1 file2 file3 file4
```

Result:

```
All files equals
```

OR

```
Files are not all equals
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With GNU diff, pass one of the files as an argument to `--from-file` and any number of others as operand:

```
$ diff -q --from-file file1 file2 file3 file4; echo $?
0
$ echo >>file3
$ diff -q --from-file file1 file2 file3 file4; echo $?
Files file1 and file3 differ
1
```

You can use globbing as usual. For example, if the current directory contains `file1`, `file2`, `file3` and `file4`, the following example compares `file2`, `file3` and `file4` to `file1`.

```
$ diff -q --from-file file*; echo $?
```

Note that the “from file” must be a regular file, not a pipe, because diff will read it multiple times.

Comment: Note that this will read the `from-file` multiple times, and thus it will not work when it's a pipe or piped `/dev/stdin` (`/dev/stdin` redirected from file does work)

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
md5sum * | awk 'BEGIN{rc=1}NR>1&&$1!=last{rc=0}{last=$1}END{exit rc}'
```

Calculates the MD5 value for each file, then compares each entry with the next, if any are different, then return a zero (true) exit status.  This would be much shorter if it returned false if different:

```
md5sum * | awk 'NR>1&&$1!=last{exit 1}{last=$1}'
```

There is no need to sort since we are just checking if any are different.

Comment: In the shorter version, I guess $1 should be used, as $0 contains file name which is unique.

Answer (score 2):

The following code should be fairly self explanatory.  `$#` is the number of file arguments, and `shift` just consumes them one at a time.  Uses `cmp -s` for silent byte-wise comparison.

```
#!/bin/sh
# diffseveral

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    printf '%s\n' "Usage: $0 file1 file2 [files ...]" >&2
    exit 2
fi

oldfile="$1"
shift

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    newfile="$1"
    if ! cmp -s "$oldfile" "$newfile"; then
         echo 'Files differ.'
         exit 1;
    fi

    shift
done

echo 'All files identical.'
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only `diff` two at a time, but it's fairly easy to check if they're all equal:

```
if diff file1 file2 && diff file2 file3 && diff file3 file4; then
    echo All equal
else
    echo Not
fi
```

If you have enough to justify a loop, use something like this:

```
alleq () {  
    for file; do 
        diff -q "$1" "$file" >/dev/null || return 1
    done
}

if alleq file1 file2 ...; then
    echo All equal
else 
    echo Not
fi
```

Comment: Clumsy if you have fifty files, or don't know how many

Comment: @DarenW Sure, if you have that many just use a loop.